# Having problem with TensorFlow not recognizing my GPU (NVIDIA 4090 RTX)

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, ubuntu, nvidia

For some reason my installation of TensorFlow on an Ubuntu Focal is not recognizing my GPU.

```
testTensorFlowTTS.py
```

```
2023-05-05 20:10:21.682174: I tensorflow/tsl/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:28] Could not find cuda drivers on your machine, GPU will not be used.
2023-05-05 20:10:21.704546: I tensorflow/tsl/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:28] Could not find cuda drivers on your machine, GPU will not be used.
2023-05-05 20:10:21.704838: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2023-05-05 20:10:22.134455: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
<CTRL-D>
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  random_device could not be read
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Script is simple test script...

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import tensorflow as tf

import yaml
import numpy as np

import IPython.display as ipd

from transformers import pipeline

from tensorflow_tts.inference import TFAutoModel
from tensorflow_tts.inference import AutoConfig
from tensorflow_tts.inference import AutoProcessor
```

```
nvidia-smi
```

```
Sat May  6 07:05:33 2023       
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 530.41.03              Driver Version: 530.41.03    CUDA Version: 12.1     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                  Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf            Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4090         Off| 00000000:41:00.0  On |                  Off |
|  0%   36C    P8               43W / 450W|    301MiB / 24564MiB |      1%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1514      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           59MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2384      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           91MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2547      G   ...39943991,1614355343741730628,131072      131MiB |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Oh, ran the script above and expected no errors.
Tried updating several tings.. including

```
python3 -m pip install nvidia-tensorrt
apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit libnvvm
```

Comment: I am still working on the root problem, but for the record, pyTorch sees my GPU's.  I also ran the following: python3 -c 'import torch; print(torch.cuda.is_available())' which results in true.

Answer (score 1):

Please go through this tensorflow official [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#linux) to install tensorflow in your system and follow the step by step instructions.

Please make sure all the system requirements are satisfied as specified in the link and set the path for all the software.

Let us know if the issue still persists. Thank you.

Comment: But that link recommends using Conda, I am trying to install it in the base OS, prefer not to use Conda

Comment: Looking at my installation, using python 3.10, the latest pip install gives me version 8.5.0.96 of nvidia-cudnn-cu11, and have tensorflow 2.12.0 installed.

Comment: Could you please check if you have installed right version of CUDA and cuDNN for GPU support compatible to installed tensorflow , python version in your system. Please refer to this [tested build configurations](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu) for the same and set the [system path](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#step-by-step_instructions) for these software as mentioned in the link inside 4. GPU setup instructions.